# convert two-dimensional array to string

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a `String[][]` to a string for display in a GUI. Here's my code:

```
String[][] tableBornes = SearchPropertiesPlugin.FillBornesTable();
String table = tableBornes.toString();
```

Here's what it produces:

> `[[Ljava.lang.String;@19b8858`

How can I get something more readable?

Comment: You're getting the reference of the array. You should iterate through all the elements there and concatenate them to get your desired output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to create one-line representation of array you can use `Arrays.deepToString`.

---

In case you want to create multi-line representation you will probably need to iterate over all rows and append result of `Array.toString(array[row])` like

```
String[][] array = { { "a", "b" }, { "c" } };

String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (String[] row : array) {
    sb.append(Arrays.toString(row))
      .append(lineSeparator);
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

Since Java 8 you can even use `StringJoiner` with will automatically add delimiter for you:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
for (String[] row : array) {
    sj.add(Arrays.toString(row));
}
String result = sj.toString();
```

or using streams

```
String result = Arrays
        .stream(array)
        .map(Arrays::toString) 
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

Answer (score 33):

try one line version

```
Arrays.deepToString(tableBornes);
```

or multiline version

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String[] s1 : tableBornes){
    sb.append(Arrays.toString(s2)).append('\n');
}
String s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: thnks, i tried this, but i want also to return in line, to print each list in one line ? how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Try [`Arrays.toString(Object[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

```
for(String[] a : tableBornes) 
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

The above code will print every array in two dimensional array `tableBornes` in newline.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String[] s1 : tableBornes){
    for(String s2 : s1){
        sb.append(s2);
    }
}
String table = sb.toString();
```

If you want to insert spaces or some other character between the items just add another `append` call within the inner loop.

Comment: yes i want to add space and also return to the line so as to have the model of the table. am wondring if there's a way to print the table directly since i have the model ?